# Overwriting all inner map values when I only want to update one map

Tags: java

I am trying to create a map of maps.  I want to be able to update these maps individually but what I am doing below is overwriting the values in all the maps, and I can't figure out why.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> cacheStatistics = initializeCacheStatistics()

static Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> initializeCacheStatistics() {
    List<String> cacheNames = Arrays.asList("cache1", "cache2",
            "cache3")

    Map<String, Integer> stats = new HashMap<>()
    stats.put("entries", 0)
    stats.put("misses", 0)
    stats.put("hits", 0)

    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> cacheStatistics = new HashMap<>()

    for (cacheName in cacheNames) {
        cacheStatistics.put(cacheName, stats)
    }

    return cacheStatistics
}
```

What I get from this is:
[cache1:[hits:0, entries:0, misses:0], cache2:[hits:0, entries:0, misses:0], cache3:[hits:0, entries:0, misses:0]]

I am trying to update the individual maps by getting a value and using it to update only the values for a single map in the map of maps:

```
static void trackCacheStatistics(String cacheStatisticsName, String cacheStatisticsTrackerName, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> cacheStatistics) {
    int entries = Integer.valueOf(getCacheEntries(cacheStatisticsName).toString())
    cacheStatistics.computeIfAbsent(cacheStatisticsTrackerName, { k -> new HashMap<>() }).put("entries", entries)

    int misses = Integer.valueOf(getCacheMisses(cacheStatisticsName).toString())
    cacheStatistics.computeIfAbsent(cacheStatisticsTrackerName, { k -> new HashMap<>() }).put("misses", misses)

    int hits = Integer.valueOf(getCacheHits(cacheStatisticsName).toString())
    cacheStatistics.computeIfAbsent(cacheStatisticsTrackerName, { k -> new HashMap<>() }).put("hits", hits)
}
```

So what I am hoping for is this:
[cache1:[hits:6, entries:3, misses:5], cache2:[hits:5, entries:1, misses:1], cache3:[hits:22, entries:5, misses:11]]

I am calling the method to update my maps like this:

```
static void validateNewCacheMissesAndEntries(String cacheStatisticsName, String cacheStatisticsTrackerName, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> cacheStatistics) {
    pollingVerifier.verify({
        assert validateCacheMisses(cacheStatisticsName) > cacheStatistics.get(cacheStatisticsTrackerName).get("misses")
    }, CACHE_STATISTICS_RETRIES)

    pollingVerifier.verify({
        assert validateCacheEntries(cacheStatisticsName) > cacheStatistics.get(cacheStatisticsTrackerName).get("entries")
    }, CACHE_STATISTICS_RETRIES)

    trackCacheStatistics(cacheStatisticsName, cacheStatisticsTrackerName, cacheStatistics)
}
```

So what I want is to see 1 map get updated, but what I am seeing is all maps get updated with the same values, like this:

[cache1:[hits:22, entries:1, misses:1], cache2:[hits:22, entries:1, misses:1], cache3:[hits:22, entries:1, misses:1]]

I call that method like this:

```
validateNewCacheMissesAndEntries(CACHE_STATISTICS_NAME, "cache1", cacheStatistics)
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong (I'm new at this and have hit a dead end).  I think there is some problem with me passing the cache name as a string into trackCacheStatistics(cacheStatisticsName, cacheStatisticsTrackerName, cacheStatistics).  Like it's not able to actually find the key and therefore it's just updating all the maps?  Sorry if I am not explaining very well.

I can't use anything higher than Java 8.

Comment: Please put in your actual code.  E.g. `for (cacheName in cacheNames) {` is not valid Java.  You are missing some terminating semi colons and you have other syntax errors as well.   Basically provide a [mre].

Comment: Sorry @WJS.  Still learning how to properly post - will remember for next time!  Thanks

Comment: You can always edit your question and make the corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are creating only one map and putting multiple references to it in the outer map:

```
Map<String, Integer> stats = new HashMap<>()
stats.put("entries", 0)
stats.put("misses", 0)
stats.put("hits", 0)

Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> cacheStatistics = new HashMap<>()

for (cacheName in cacheNames) {
    cacheStatistics.put(cacheName, stats)
}
```

If you put your inner map creation in the loop you will putting multiple maps in the outer map rather than multiple references to the same one.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> cacheStatistics = new HashMap<>()

for (cacheName in cacheNames) {
    Map<String, Integer> stats = new HashMap<>()
    stats.put("entries", 0)
    stats.put("misses", 0)
    stats.put("hits", 0)
    cacheStatistics.put(cacheName, stats)
}
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks!